# get the element passing variable name as attribute value

Tags: jquery

I have multiple checkboxes and its associated textareas for comments in the page. So when I check the checkbox, its realted textarea should be displayed.

**But these textareas are not direct siblings of these checkboxes**. So I need to provide the data-attr* to the textareas value same as id of these checkboxes to identify it.

But how do I get the child element(textareas) of the associated parent(checkbox.). The below is what I am trying to achieve.

```
id = $(this).attr('id') //gets id of checkbox.

child_elem = $('textarea').attr('[data-comments="'+id+'"]') //To identify and return the textarea which has data-comments = id of checkbox.
```

Also are there any jquery plugins which does the same functionality, so that it can be generic and re-usable because I have to achiveve the same functionality with other elements like select boxes, radio buttons etc.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what your HTML looks like, I'm struggling to visualise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [data](http://api.jquery.com/data) and [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter) method:

```
child_elem = $('textarea').filter(function(){
   return $(this).data('comments') === id;
})//now you can bind here 
//for example
.addClass('co');
```

Comment: what if I want to return that that html element if it is same as id??

Comment: You can use .val() method to get textarea value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it as a selector, [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
child_elem = $('textarea[data-comments="' + id + '"]')
//same using filter child_elem = $('textarea').filter('[data-comments="' + id + '"]')
```

Your code will try to return an attribute value called `[data-comments="<id>"]` from the first textarea of the page,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show text area when checkbox is checked and hide it when unchecked, you can try this

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chckbx" /> this is a checkbox 
<input type="textarea" id = "txtbox"  value="textarea value" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#txtbox").hide();
$("#chckbx").change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#txtbox').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#txtbox").hide();
    }

});
```

Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Ujwal_15/C5WxK/1351/

Let me know if this helps.

Thanks